# Do analytic properties hold in an arbitrary ordered field?

Tags: field-theory, ordered-fields

Given an ordered field, we can view it as a field formally equipped with some analytical notions which come from $\mathbb R$, like order and derivative. So I'm curious if $F$ also carries some analytical properties of $\mathbb R$ such as several mean value properties. To begin with, I'd like to know:

> Let $(F,+,×,\leqslant)$ be an ordered field, $a,b,c\in F$, $f\in F[x]$, can we prove that:
>
> If for any $c\in(a,b)$ we have $f'(c)\geqslant0$ (resp. $f'(c)>0$), then  $f(a)\leqslant f(b)$ (resp. $f(a)<f(b)$).

Comment: Why would the field inherit anything from the reals? The rationals lack most of the properties you would want.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm embarrassed not noticing that. But I think rationals only lacks the first property I listed, which I have deleted. Do you think the second one holds more generally?

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry I'm not very familiar with real closure. Do you mean that $f'(c)>0$ for $c\in(a,b)$ in $F$ implies $f'(c)>0$ for $c\in(a,b)$ in the real closure of $F$?

Comment: Hmmm, never mind, that statement isn't true...but the counterexample to it I found doesn't give a counterexample to the original question, so I still don't know what's going on.

Comment: @EricWofsey Would you mind decribe a bit of the counterexample you found if not complicated? I'm a little curious about that…

Comment: The example is $F=\mathbb{R}(t)$ with $x$ infinite and $f'(x)=(x^2-t)(x^2-t-1)$.  Note that $f'(c)>0$ for all $c\in F$ (since there is no $c\in F$ such that $t\leq c^2\leq t+1$), but if you adjoin $\sqrt{t}$ and $\sqrt{t+1}$ to $F$ then $f'(c)<0$ for any $c$ between $\sqrt{t}$ and $\sqrt{t+1}$.  However, it seems to nonetheless be true that the antiderivative $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $F$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @EricWofsey Very heuristic, thanks.

Comment: You might find the articles by Ron Brown interesting http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/mathfiles/rolle_Illinois.pdf